# Updating php serialize array value in database

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

So we have historic logs in a database that contain old user data. We don't want to delete the logs but rather just *** out some of the data that is in there. Its stored in MySQL in a field as an array that has been serialized.

```
a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:17:"user data";}
```

How can I update the value of test (user data)? either via MySQL or php so it would look like the below? This effects hundreds of rows.

```
a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:17:"***";}
```

This is what I have just tried to retrieve some data

```
$sqltext = "SELECT log_data FROM log WHERE log_data != '' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query ($sqltext) or die(SqlError(__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__));

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$deserialized = unserialize($row->log_data);
var_dump($deserialized);
```

which returns this: bool(false)

The array contains a bunch of stuff including html

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can make a loop, for each row unserialize, replace what you need, and serialize back.

Comment: have you looked at the functions [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)?

Comment: No I haven't tried anything yet - don't know how to start

Comment: I think maybe starting with @caCtus suggestion using the two linked functions would be a good start. Then come back with a more specific issue regarding which part you are having a problem with.

Comment: ok I have updated my post

Comment: Just pointing out that `a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:17:"user data";} ` is not valid serialized code. `user data` is only 9 characters. so it should be `a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:9:"user data";}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I needed to pull out the serialized data, de-serialize it, change a value in multiple rows and update again re-serialized.

```
while ($row_something = mysql_fetch_assoc($something)) {
    $log_id       = $row_something['log_id'];
    $deserialized = unserialize($row_something['log_data']);

    foreach ($deserialized AS $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'user_data') {
            $deserialized['user_data'] = "***";
        }

        $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE log SET log_data=%s WHERE log_id=%s", 
        GetSQLValueString(serialize($deserialized), "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($row_something['log_id'], "int"));

        mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
        $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning** MySQL Function set is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

I suspect maybe the results of the query are not coming back right. When I test ( http://codepad.org/Rhlwm82A ) the following code, it works as expected:

```
<?php

$row = array("log_data" => 'a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:9:"user data";}');

$deserialized = unserialize($row['log_data']);
var_dump($deserialized);

?>
```

So maybe you need to check that you have a result or that it's serialized data:

```
<?php
$sqltext = "SELECT log_data FROM log WHERE log_data != '' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query ($sqltext);
if(!$result){
    die(SqlError(__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__));
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$deserialized = unserialize($row['log_data']);
var_dump($deserialized);
?>
```

Comment: The `mysql function set` is deprecated, not `mysql`